# Extra padding on menu in every browser only on one computer

Tags: css, browser, menu, padding, rollover

I'm rather per perplexed by this. When I view my web page on Chrome, FireFox, IE9, Opera, or Safari on my main computer, there is an extra 3px of top padding on my menu's rollover.

When I check on my other two computers in the house, on all said browsers above (plus IE8), the menu doesn't have the 3px extra padding.

I have reset the browsers on my main computer, though I'm thinking something external must be impacting the page rendering, since it's happening on all of my browsers...? It wouldn't be a monitor condition would it? I have not done anything fancy about monitor calibration. All my browsers are at zoom 100%.

Main comp: Windows 7
Other two comps: Windows 7 and Windows XP

Any guessing about why this may be would be super helpful. Thanks.

CSS:

```
#access {
clear: both;
display: block;
float: left;
margin: 0px 0 40px 0;
padding:0;
width: 100%;
text-align:left;
/* height:54px; */
background-image:url(images/menu-bar.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:top center;
}

#access ul {
list-style: none;
margin: 0 0 0 20px;
padding: 0;
width:100%;
}

#access ul li { display:inline;padding:0;margin:0; }

#access li {
background-image:url(images/menu-bar-divider.gif); 
background-repeat:no-repeat;
background-position:top right;
}


#access ul li a {
color: #ffffff;
display:block;
float:left;
padding: 18px 39px 17px 39px;
text-decoration: none;
font-size:16px;
text-shadow: 0px 1px #c86209;
}

#access li a:link { }
#access li:last-child { background-image:none; }    
#access a:hover { text-shadow: none;background-image:url(images/menu-bar-hover.gif);background-repeat:repeat-x;background-position:bottom center;color:#000000!important;}
#access a:visited { color:#ffffff!important;}
```

Comment: Can you paste computed style from chrome on both machines the one which shows correct and one which shows open. When you copy computed style for padding open it to view where it has come from and paste that here via screenshot or something similar so we can see or you might have solved it by that time.

Answer (score 0):

Possible scenarios:

1. is this a CMS? are you maybe logged in as an admin in the other
   pc? I had the same problem with Wordpress. http://wordpress.org/support/topic/31-update-causing-28px-top-spacing-in-html-body
2. do you have any addons, plugins, adware installed that are
   interfering with your layout?
3. Did you use a CSS reset or
   Normalize? (one of them not both) This can help you solve

similar issues.

1. http://necolas.github.com/normalize.css/
2. http://developer.yahoo.com/yui/reset/

Could you try reproducing your case in JSFIDDLE or http://tinkerbin.com/ ?